# Find the density function and distribution function of $X+Y$ and $X-Y$

Tags: probability

Let $X$, $Y$ random independent variables. $X$ uniformly in $[-a,a]$. $Y$  uniformly in the interval $[-a,2a]$. Find the density function and distribution function of $X+Y$ and $X-Y$

**My work:**

As $X\sim U[-a,a]$ then

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2a} && if & -a\leq x\leq a\\
0 && \text{other case}
\end{cases}$

As $Y\sim U[-a,2a]$ then

$f(y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3a} && if & -a\leq y\leq 2a\\
0 && \text{other case}
\end{cases}$

Here i'm a little confused. Can someone help me?

Comment: You have already written down the marginal pdf for $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Have you learned how to use convolution to compute the pdf of $X + Y$ and $X - Y$ respectively? Or, by independence, you already know the joint pdf of $(X, Y)$. Have you learned how to transform this joint pdf to the joint pdf of $(X + Y, X - Y)$?

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $ X $ and $ Y $ are *independent* random variables,
then the probability density function of $ X + Y $ is the convolution of $ f_X(\cdot) $
and $ f_Y(\cdot) $ (which denote, respectively, their density functions).

The convolution of two function, $ (f * g)(z) $, is defined as

$$
(f * g)(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)g(z-t) ~\mathrm dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z-t)g(t) ~\mathrm dt
$$

First let's solve for the density function of $ X+ Y $.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(f*g)(z)
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(t) g_X(z-t) ~\mathrm dt \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbf 1_{t \in [-a, a]} \frac{1}{2a} \mathbf 1_{z-t \in [-a, 2a]} \frac{1}{3a} ~\mathrm dt\\
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbf 1_{t \in [-a, a]} \frac{1}{2a} \mathbf 1_{t \in [-a-z, 2a-z]} \frac{1}{3a} ~\mathrm dt\\
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbf 1_{t \in [-a, a]} \frac{1}{2a} \mathbf 1_{t \in [z-2a, a+z]} \frac{1}{3a} ~\mathrm dt\\
& = \frac{1}{6a^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbf 1_{t \in [-a, a]}  \mathbf 1_{t \in [z-2a, a+z]} ~\mathrm dt\\
& = \frac{1}{6a^2} \mathbf 1_{z\in[-2a,3a]}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbf 1_{t \in [\max\{-a,z-2a\},\min\{ a,z+a\}]} ~\mathrm d t \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

You can continue this by performing a case analysis on $ z $ (i.e. when $ z < 0 $, $ z > 0 $). Then, once you get the density function, you can simply integrate it to obtain the distribution function.